# SPM Cannot Resolve Package Graph with certain internet connection

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a strange problem where SPM is stuck at the `"Resolving Package Graph"` stage forever.

The strange part is that this problem only occurs when I'm connected to my home Wifi. If I try to fetch dependencies by connecting to my phone's personal hotspot, or when I'm connected to the Wifi at the office, this problem does not occur and SPM can successfully resolve packages and fetch everything.

Also worth mentioning that when I'm connected to the Wifi at home, I have no problem with the usage of any application or browser, this only seems to affect SPM.

I've tried with multiple Xcode versions (12.5.0 and 12.5.1) and didn't make a difference.

Has anyone else encountered the same problem? If so, how could you work around this?

Comment: Simple reset your router or try to clean DNS cache on it because sometimes it can be stuck for some domains.

Comment: I tried resetting the router but that didn't help either. I will try cleaning the DNS cache next then, thank you!

Comment: Cleaning DNS cache didn't help either :/ @iUrii

Comment: Yup.  Same problem for me.   SPM resolution is extremely slow over Wifi, but works flawlesly when connecting via cable, VPN or Phone.  I have a "modern" mesh system (Linksys Velop MX4200)

I've tried everything and it simply dies when resolving dependencies on some packages.